# cucumber select multiple checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm working on a Rails 3 application with Cucumber 1.1.1 and I'm trying to select multiple checkboxes in my cucumber scenarios.

Here is my multiple checkboxes in haml:

```
- for diocese in Diocese.all
  = check_box_tag "clergy[diocese_ids][]", diocese.id, @clergy.dioceses.include?(diocese)
  = f.label diocese.name
  %br
```

Here is my cucumber step

```
When /^I check the (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) of the "([^"]*)" checkboxes$/ do |index, junk, group|
  page.all("input[id=\"clergy_diocese_ids_\"]")[index.to_i - 1].check('clergy_diocese_ids_') 
end
```

Here is my cucumber test:

```
  @wip
  Scenario: New Clergy
    Given I am on the clergies page
    When I follow "New Clergy"
    And I fill in "Surname" with "Wells"
    And I fill in "Given names" with "Robin"
    And I check the 1st of the "diocese" checkboxes
    And I check the 2nd of the "diocese" checkboxes
    And I press "Create Clergy"
    Then I should see "Clergy was successfully created."
```

The error I get when running my test:

```
    And I check the 1st of the "diocese" checkboxes                                    # fea
tures/step_definitions/clergy_steps.rb:37                                                  
      cannot check field, no checkbox with id, name, or label 'clergy_diocese_ids_' found (C
apybara::ElementNotFound)                                                                  
      ./features/step_definitions/clergy_steps.rb:38:in `/^I check the (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) of
 the "([^"]*)" checkboxes$/'                                                               
      features/clergy_new.feature:17:in `And I check the 1st of the "diocese" checkboxes'
```

I've tried playing around with the page.all selector but I cannot work it out.

Comment: Have you checked the rendered page output to check to format of the id attribute on the checkboxes?

Comment: Yes I used firebug under firefox to check my checkboxes id's.

Comment: From the looks of your cucumber step it looks like your test is expecting all the checkboxes to share the same ID. Do you need to use string interpolation to form the correct ID for the checkbox you need to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, its not the job of Cucumber to select checkboxes and interact with the UI. Cucumber parses the feature files and executes the corresponding step definitions that match. What you put in each step definition block is up to you.

Since your step definition code appears to be using Capybara, I suggest viewing [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006869/1118492).