# Select elements from checkbox-group with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have a lot of rows like this:

```
<input id="car_ids_" name="car_ids[]" value="142" type="checkbox"> Car 142
<input id="car_ids_" name="car_ids[]" value="143" type="checkbox"> Car 143
<input id="car_ids_" name="car_ids[]" value="144" type="checkbox"> Car 144
<input id="car_ids_" name="car_ids[]" value="145" type="checkbox"> Car 145
```

I want this behaviour since i saw it in this railscast: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast

When i test myself, it works, but when I try to select some elements with Capybara, i dont know how?

```
before(:each) do
  check "car_ids_:first"
  check "car_ids_:last"
end
```

I get always

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       cannot check field, no checkbox with id, name, or label 'car_ids_:first' found
```

Can you help me how this works?
I want to select f.e. the second and the third element?

UPDATE:

```
  find(:css, "#car_ids_[value='#{@car1.id}']").set(true)
  => find(:css, "#car_ids_[value='#{@car1.id}']").checked?
  ==> "checked"
  find(:css, "#car_ids_[value='#{@car2.id}']").set(nil)
  => find(:css, "#car_ids_[value='#{@car1.id}']").checked?
  ==> nil
  find(:css, "#car_ids_[value='#{@car3.id}']").set(true)
  => find(:css, "#car_ids_[value='#{@car1.id}']").checked?
  ==> "checked"

  select("Deactivate", :from => "car_action")

  click_button "Submit"

  page.body.should have_content "Updated cars!"

  @user.cars[0].active?.should == true
  @user.cars[1].active?.should == false
  @user.cars[2].active?.should == true
```

But in the end, the checkbox values are not passed to the controller! I dont know why....
The checkboxes seem checked (but if i open the page with save_and_open_page they are also not checked?)

Comment: If I recall well: `find("#car_ids_").first.check`

Comment: This is dangerous since capybara does not guarantee that the elements in the collection are returned in the same order they appear in the markup.

Comment: Got the solution there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297624/how-to-check-a-checkbox-in-capybara

Comment: What made you think the controller is not getting the values? Have you checked this in the `params` hash?

Comment: Yeah, the params-hash is full with the common informations, but no car_ids_-array. when i try it in browser it works... argh

Comment: Hard to tell... Can you show the code for the form, the controller action and the test you're running? A gist would be good if there's too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to tell capybara to check the boxes by their labels. If you have the @cars collection at your disposal, you can do something like this:

```
[@cars[1], @cars[2]].each do |car|
  check("Car #{car.id}")
end
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, if you want to specifically access 2nd and 3rd elements without regard to what collection items they refer to, you can wrap your inputs in a div with some id (to narrow the selector scope), e.g. `car-checkboxes`, and then do this:

```
find(:css, "#car-checkboxes input:nth-child(2)").click
```

or

```
find(:css, "#car-checkboxes input:nth-child(2)").set(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i cant use labels since there are a lot of informations in the rows and i dont need a special label for each...

Comment: Could you look at my update? The checkboxes are now checked but it doesnt work.. :S

Comment: I'm an idiot.. I had some code mixed up and reloaded the page after filling out the form.. and then i wondered why the form is empty.. thanks!